# The tilted labyrinth - Can you find the fastest path in this 3D-puzzle? (Simulator now included.)

Tags: geometry, mechanical-puzzles, optimization, visual

This is a puzzle was inspired by the board game [labyrinth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(board_game)), which I very much enjoyed as a kid.

It either requires very good 3D-visualization skills in your brain or some paper & scissors work. (Hence *mechanical* puzzle).

Thanks to [**Kevin**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1497/kevin), there is now also a Javascript [simulator](http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/2/) for this puzzle, which makes things way easier.

---

---

### Goal

Imagine you have a labelled board of 25 fields like the following:
[image: board]

You also have 25 dice which are all build up by the same mesh:
[image: dice mesh]

These dice are placed on a 5x5 field grid to create a labyrinth with the faces showing upwards.

[image: Starting position]

You start out on the top-left position (A1), and you goal is to reach all other three corners (E1, E5, A5 ) *in arbitrary sequence*. You want to do this with *minimum amount of steps*. Note that 'passing through' one of the corners in a single move is valid for the purpose of the goal. (You do not have to end a move in a corner. )

### Rules

- A single **step** consists of the sequence of **first tilting** a *row **or** column* and **then moving** from your current location along 'open paths' for an arbitrary distance. (You may do only one of the two, but not change the sequence order.)
- When tilting, you have to **tilt all** dice of the row/column in the same direction by 90 degree. (*Fixed tiles of the row/column stay obviously unchanged.*)
- You **must not tilt** a row/column which includes your **current position** on the grid.
- the board does **not warp around**. It is not possible to leave it on one side and renter from the other side.

### Notation

- **Tilt-notation** includes either the letter (column) or the number (row) of the tilt, and either + or - to indicated direction (*see example below*).
- **Move-notation** includes start and end position given by the grid-coordinates (*see example below*).

### Example

Starting from the start position given above, you first all dice of column B in + direction. (*Imagine the top of the dice tilting downwards.*)

> Tilt-Notation: **(B+)**

[image: Tilt1]

Now you move the marker.

> Move-Notation: **[A1 -> B1]**

[image]

So the whole step would have the notation:

> Step 1: **(B+)  [A1 -> B1]**

---

---

## The puzzle question:

What is the minimum number of steps you need to visit all 4 corners of the grid (starting in A1) from the given starting situation:

[image: Starting position]

You have to give all steps in the notation explained above.

## The current record for this puzzle is 7 moves.

Comment: Shall I assume wrapping is not allowed?

Comment: Do the dice move when you tilt them? For example, in the tilt B+, does the die at the top of the column then become the die second from the top, or does it rotate but stay at the top of the column?

Comment: My understanding is the dice stay where they are and just rotate themselves accordingly

Comment: Are you required to move to a new spot after a "tilt" is made? or is [A1->A1] acceptable?

Comment: If I move through a corner but don't end the turn on the corner, does that count as "reaching" the corner? Ex. If I do "D1 -> E2".

Comment: I've programmed a tool that helps you test out move sequences. It is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/1/).

Comment: update to previous comment: [now with undo functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/2/).

Comment: @Kevin Will your tool stay under this link "for long"? If so, I would like to link it up from the main question. It's actually good fun to use it.(if you want, you could add a variable puzzle size and random goal-points, and hurray you (we) have created a puzzle-game app. )

Comment: @BmyGuest, yes, that link should remain valid for the foreseeable future. The web site owner [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171371/how-long-does-jsfiddle-host-your-code-for) that scripts are stored permanently. (Of course, we can't rule out the possibility of catastrophic failure, ex. a meteor landing on his data center, so it may be prudent to save a local copy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a 7-move answer.

> (B+),
> (C+),
> (D-),
> (D-),
> (2+), [A1 -> E1],
> (B-), [E1 -> A5],
> (D-), [A5 -> E5]

Also, obviously, done with help from Kevin's tool.

Comment: Hi @Monk, welcome to Puzzling SE! It's really great to find impressive answer from a new user like you! :D Hope you enjoy being here~

Comment: Certainly a better answer! I've moved my check, well done.

Answer (score 6):

NEW ANSWER: 10 Turns (I used Kevin's interactive tool for this one)

> (2-)
> (2-)
> (3+)
> (4+)
> (4+)
> (C+), [A1 -> C5]
> (4-)
> (3-)
> (2+), [C5 -> E1]
> (3+) [E1 -> E5]

OLD ANSWER: 13 turns

Just to get the ball rolling my moves are as follows (I created an interactive version in Excel, so there is plenty of margin for error.):

> (B+)
>  (C+)
>  (D+)
>  (E+)
>  (E+) [A1->E1]
>  (2-)
>  (3+)
>  (4+)
>  (5-) [E1->E5]
>  (4-)
>  (B+)
>  (B+)
>  (A+) [E5->A5]

Comment: Believe me, it is nothing special... Though, can you at least check my answer? I'm interested to know if it works correctly....

Comment: This sequence does appear to work correctly. +1.