# The Tiled Labyrinth Returns

Tags: visual, geometry, optimization

This is a variant on [The Tiled Labyrinth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/the-tilted-labyrinth-can-you-find-the-fastest-path-in-this-3d-puzzle-simulat).

The rules are the same, except that the goal has changed.

You will probably want to use [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/2/) which was created for the initial puzzle but applies equally well to this version.

Summarizing the rules for those too lazy to read the original problem:

- You have a board consisting of a set of 5x5 dice, each of which has paths on the different sides.
  [image]
- The starting position is
  [image]
- You may rotate all the dice in a given column up or down
- You may rotate all the dice in a given row left or right
- You may not rotate the dice in the row or column corresponding to your current location
- After any rotation you may move to any other location that is connected to your current location.

The new goal: Create a single path that connects all four corners of the board.  A sample solution might look like this:

[image]

A few notes:

- Any solution that creates a path between all four corners will be accepted, It does not have to be the same as my sample solution above.
- I will be looking for the solution that involves the fewest rotations (I will not count the number of moves)
- Here is a 28-rotation sequence that results in the end position above, but your goal is to do better.  It also includes a hint about how I generated the sequence

> (B+), (C+), (D+), (D+), (2-), (D+), (2+), (D-), (5-), (C+), (5+), (C-), (5+), (D-), (5-), (D+), (B+), (5+), (B-), (5-), (B-), (5+), (B+), (5-), (5+), (E+), (5-), (E-), [A1 -> E5]
> The idea behind the subsequence "(5+), (E+), (5-), (E-)" is to rotate the die at E5 without changing the rest of the board

Comment: To make this puzzle more stand alone, you'd need to show the pattern of the dice and the starting position.

Comment: Edited the problem to make it more stand alone

Comment: The OP probably doesn't know this, but this question netted him the second and last Tumbleweed badge on Puzzling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an upper bound, here's a solution using <s>19</s> 13 moves that doesn't require the movement of ball at all (which isn't a great optimization since ball movements are free!).

> (B+), (C+), (D+), (2+), (5+), (D+), (E+), (C+), (C+), (5-), (C+), (C+), (5+)

I used Kevin's script (http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/2/)

Final position:

> [image: Screenshot of Kevin's script with 13-move solution]

Comment: Two notes: 1. The "Undo" line gives away your solution, 2. Keep working, I have a solution with 16 moves

Comment: @EugeneStyer, noted! I found a 13 move solution (and put it under spoiler tags!)

Answer (score 1):

Update: A computer search has come up with a 8-move solution. (Actually multiple 8-move solutions but I'll only give this one):

> (5+), (4+), (2-), (3+), (C+), (D-), (D-), (B+)

The final position for this solution is:
[image]

**Original Post:**
I'll add this as an answer since I found a different 13-move solution:

> (B+), (C+), (D+), (D+), (2-), (3+), (4+), [A1 -> B1], (2+), (4-), (A+), (2-), (4+), (A-)

With a final position of:
[image]